# How can I extract the specific words from a string?

Tags: python

I need a program to accept a string and extract specific words to get an output like this in Python?

Input string:

```
My name is somename. I am from India and I'm an Engineer.
```

The output should be:

```
Name: Somename
Location: India
Profession: Engineer
```

Please, can anyone help me regarding this?

Comment: The [python-requests] tag is often mis-used like this, read the tag entry please. Also the question implies a lack of research effort, please revise it and read the SO guidelines

Comment: python requests is a library. SO is not a code service

Comment: I am looking for a python program/code to extract specific words from the string. TA

Comment: You can use libary like Spacy (https://spacy.io/) or mitie(https://github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE) to extract Name Entity Recognition (NER).

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear from your question what you actually want.

If it is a simple regex query:

```
import re

strng = "My name is somename. I am from India and I'm an Engineer."
mobj = re.match("My name is (?P<name>.*). I am from (?P<location>.*) and I'm an (?P<profession>.*).", strng)
if mobj:
    print("Name: {}".format(mobj.groupdict()['name']))
    print("Location: {}".format(mobj.groupdict()['location']))
    print("Profession: {}".format(mobj.groupdict()['profession']))
```

If you want a more natural language parser then try the options that Hiadore suggested: Spacy (spacy.io) or mitie(github.com/mit-nlp/MITIE)

Answer (score 0):

Code:-

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
doc2 = nlp("My name is John. I am from India and I'm an Engineer.")
print([(X.text, X.label_) for X in doc2.ents])
```

Result :-

```
   [('John', 'PERSON'), ('India', 'GPE'), ('Engineer', 'PERSON')]
```